# Calculate the average of hourly data of three sensors

Tags: r, time-series, mean

I am trying to calculate the average of hourly data of three sensors but the hourly timestamps of all three sensors are different. How is it possible to measure the average of hourly data of all three sensors at a regular interval of hours say- 01:00,02:00,03:00 and so on.

And also is it possible to start an extensible time series with a specific time which is before the first timestamp of the given dataset so that the extra timestamps have NA values and i can use na.rm=TRUE while calculating mean.:

```
  library(xts)
 library(forecast)
 data1$V1<-as.POSIXct(paste(data1$V1, data1$V2), format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") 
     sensid<-as.factor(data1$V4)

 #For Temp

 for(i in 1:length(levels(sensid)))
  {
   l[[i]]=data.frame(data1$V6[data1$V4==i])
   l[[i]]<-xts(l[[i]],order.by=data1$V1[data1$V4==i])
   if(length(which (is.na(l[[i]])))<length(l[[i]]))
     {      
      wAvgt[[i]]<-apply.weekly(l[[i]], function(x) sapply(x,mean,na.rm=TRUE)) #Weekly   Average of Temp
      dAvgt[[i]]<- apply.daily(l[[i]], function(x) sapply(x,mean,na.rm=TRUE)) #Daily Average of Temp
      hrAvgt[[i]] <- period.apply(l[[i]], endpoints(l[[i]], on = "hours", 1), function(x) sapply(x,mean,na.rm=TRUE)) #Hourly Average of Temp

     #For forecasting future values
     aritw[[i]]<-auto.arima(wAvgt[[i]]) #Weekly Forecast ARIMA model using ARIMA 
     foretw[[i]]<-forecast.Arima(aritw[[i]],h=5) #Forecast of Weekly Average of Temp

     arith[[i]]<-auto.arima(hrAvgt[[i]]) #Hourly Forecast ARIMA model using ARIMA 
     foreth[[i]]<-forecast.Arima(arith[[i]],h=50)#Forecast of Hourly Average of Temp

     aritd[[i]]<-auto.arima(dAvgt[[i]]) #Daily Forecast ARIMA model using ARIMA 
     foretd[[i]]<-forecast.Arima(aritd[[i]],h=10)#Forecast of Daily Average of Temp
    }
else
    {
     next
    }
 }
```

I have 27 sensors data. so i m trying to caclulate hourly,weekly and daily average of each sensors but each sensor provides 4 critical parameters like - blood pressure, temperature, Pulse and WBC. The above loop provided is only for temperature of 27 sensors. I have a bed connected to some 3 sensors and each sensor has 4 critical parameters to measure. I m concerned only with temperature for now. I need to calculate hourly average of temp for that bed only. So, initially i measure hourly average of any 3 given sensors each and then i intend to take the hourly average between these 3 sensors.

The problem i m facing here is each hourly average has different number of rows and different timestamps. How to normalise all the timestamps?

If the starting timestamp of sensor 1 is 2004-02-28 00:59:16, sensor 2 is 2004-02-28 01:08:23, sensor 3 is 2004-02-28 01:19:34, it is not possible to normalise them by any methods i know of yet.

Please help me find the hourly average of three sensors.

Comment: I would consider adding more tags to your question (right now you only have the `R` tag).

Comment: If you post a piece of your data it will be easier to give you an answer. If possible, please post the output from `dput(x)`, where `x` are the temperatures recorded at one sensor. If the data set is large you could post just some of the observations.